# What is the most reasonable declaration of an array for a string of fixed length in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am new to C, so this question might sound dumb. I have a const char* variable with length 2 always. Now I need to pass it on to a struct variable. Should the struct variable be a char array[2] (since it needs only two bytes always) or be a char*. The reason why I am asking is, using a char* will create space for a pointer (4bytes or 8 bytes) but I really need only 2 bytes. Which is the best way to do it? If using a char array[] is the better approach, should I use strcpy to copy the char* variable to char array[]??

Comment: You have 2 chars, but are you counting the null-terminating character? If so, I would simply use a single char, otherwise, you should have an array of length 3.

Comment: I think @Joe has the correct, direct answer, but I would comment that saving a couple of bytes here or there shouldn't necessarily be as significant criteria in your choice compared to functionally how you want to use the data (what implementation is the least complex and most robust) and how you might want to modify/expand the implementation later. Saving bytes would come into higher priority if you have an application that truly is very memory sensitive, or if you are saving a very large number of bytes, or if it impacting real time performance negatively.

Answer (score 5):

If you are confident that it is always 2 bytes, there's no problem using an array. Just always use `strncpy` and friends to make sure you don't overrun. Remember to make it 3 bytes long to accommodate the null char. You can get a pointer to your array for reading purposes and that behave identical to a `char*` to `malloc`ed memory.

Comment: So after I set the array to be char a[3], should I explicitly set a[2] ='\0' or doing a strncpy automatically does that?

Comment: Careful with strncpy - if the length of the string to copy is equal to the length of the buffer, it won't terminate it.

Comment: Yes, always pass 2 to strncpy. You should initialize the array to all zeroes to begin with so it's always a valid 'string'.

Comment: Okay. Now I have another question, what if the char* variable am passing on is empty?

Comment: That's fine. As long as you start with an array of null values, it will appear to be empty to any string-handling functions.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I have a const char** *variable with length 2 always. Now I need to pass it on to a struct variable"*

If you know that the string will always have a length 2, it is perfectly reasonable to use an array of fixed size 3 (including a null-terminating character):

```
struct myStruct {
    char code[3];
};
```

and somewhere:

```
struct myStruct m;
const char* src = "ab"; 
strncpy(&myStruct.code[0], src, 3);
```

but in case you can not ensure that the length of `src` will be no more than 2, you better do:

```
strncpy(&myStruct.code[0], src, 2);
myStruct.code[2] = '\0';
```